# how to create an object from model

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have problem with creating an object from model in typescript.

```
    export interface ICompliance {
      id?: number;
      notes?: any;
      dueDate?: Moment;
      type?: ComplianceType;
      createdBy?: string;
      updatedBy?: string;
      updatedAt?: Moment;
      createdAt?: Moment;
      file?: IFile;
      project?: IProject;
    }

    export class Compliance implements ICompliance {
      constructor(
        public id?: number,
        public notes?: any,
        public dueDate?: Moment,
        public type?: ComplianceType,
        public createdBy?: string,
        public updatedBy?: string,
        public updatedAt?: Moment,
        public createdAt?: Moment,
        public file?: IFile,
        public project?: IProject
      ) {}
    }
```

I am newbie in typescript. How to create an object from model ? any advice ? thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [typescript interface initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23412033/typescript-interface-initialization)

Answer (score 2):

private obj = new Compliance ({...});

Answer (score 1):

Since typescript it is just a superset of a javascript you can create object with `new` operator.

```
new Compliance();
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an object based on your model. You can just use it as a type instead of implementing it on class.

```
export class Compliance {
  message: ICompliance;
}
```

Comment: and don't forget to import it in you component's .ts file. Ex. import { ICompliance } from 'src/app/models/icompliance.model';

Comment: Yes. If the interface is not in the same file. Make sure to import it.