# Typescript: Unable to set value to interface property in Angular project

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am working on angular and trying to add basic auth with jwt with following code:

```
private authProvider(
    username: string,
    password: string
  ): Observable<IServerAuthResponse> {


    let accessToken: IServerAuthResponse;
    this.http.post<any>(CCommonUrl.LOGIN, {
      username,
      password
    }, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe((res) => {
      // console.log(res.json);
      console.log(res.headers);
      console.log(res.headers.get('Authorization'));
      accessToken.Authorization = res.headers.get('Authorization');
    });
    return of(accessToken);
```

**The Interface**

```
export interface IServerAuthResponse {
  Authorization: string;
}
```

now `console.log` is showing token but I am unable to assign value to `accessToken.Authorization`. The code is failing with following error

> core.js:7187 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'Authorization' of
>   undefined
>       at SafeSubscriber._next (auth.service.ts:60)

Any Insight will be helpfull

Edit: All I need to get value inside interface. Since token is coming in header and Therefore I am unable to map it directly to interface ]

Edit2: as far duplicate is concerned, that question had class but in this case its interface

Comment: Because accessToken is not initialized.

Comment: Have you created the `accessToken` anywhere ? You have declared it but I don't think it is instantiated anywhere unless I am missing something.

Comment: AccessToken is not initialized which is causing the problem. See  https://stackoverflow.com/a/23413375/9958058 comment which explain in detail. Also, another way is to use class instead of interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interface is not an Instance of an object so you need to Initialise the object like

```
let accessToken: IServerAuthResponse = {Authorization: ''};
```

and then you can use this line

```
accessToken.Authorization = res.headers.get('Authorization');
```

Answer (score 1):

The `accessToken` variable needs to first be initialized.

```
export interface IServerAuthResponse {
  Authorization?: string;
}

let accessToken: IServerAuthResponse = {}

...
}, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe((res) => {
      // console.log(res.json);
      console.log(res.headers);
      console.log(res.headers.get('Authorization'));
      accessToken['Authorization'] = res.headers.get('Authorization');
    });
```